# The nth Root of the 2x2 Square Matrix

Tags: matrices

How do I find the nth root of the 2x2 square matrix
[0,1;
1,0]?

Is there any explicit formula to get the answer?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried diagonalizing the matrix?

Comment: Could you tell me more details on how to do that? Many thanks

Comment: It's a standard topic in linear algebra. If you search for "matrix diagonalization", you will find many results, including tutorials, YouTube videos, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all $n$th roots, then you need to diagonalize your matrix by finding all eigenvalues and eigenvectors (since it's diagonalizable) and then compute all $n$th roots of the eigenvalues. Your eigenvectors are $[1,1]$ and $[1,-1]$ with eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$ respectively. Therefore the general form of the $n$th root will be

$$MDM^{-1}$$

where $M = [1\,\, 1; 1 -1]$ and $D = [1^{1/n} \,\,\,\,0; 0 \, \, \, \, (-1)^{1/n}]$.

The set of all possible $n$th roots of $1$ and $-1$ are complex numbers. You can use the identity $e^{i \pi} = -1$ to solve for all possible roots.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I think  $D$ should be equal to $ [1^{1/n} \,\,\,\,0;  0 \,\,\,\, (-1)^{1/n}]$ if I am not wrong.

Comment: Yes you're right, sorry for the confusion. I've updated my answer.